# What would be a (write-only) counterpart to System.Data.IDataReader?

Tags: c#, datatable, idatareader, writeonly

**Background**

I have a data processing app, where I have separated the "processing" modules from the "import" units.
The "processing" modules get their data from arbitrary sources using the `IDataReader` interface provided by the importer modules which neatly provide field metadata and access to the field data, and allows unidirectional processing of the data. This meets my demands perfectly.

Now after my processing has completed (or potentially while it is still running), I would want to "export" the generated data in a similar fashion, and my mind expected there to be an write-only `IDataWriter` interface, which would allow for setting field values and adding new rows.

Unfortunately, the `IDataWriter` interface provided by MS is for a different use (stream writing)

My app is entirely written in C#, .Net8 and uses loose coupling (interfaces) and modular/plugins approach as much as possible.

I'm pretty sure I am no the first one encountering this, but nevertheless found an "aha obvious" counterpart to `IDataReader` ;)

(BTW - I am not native english speaking, so cut me some slack here)

**The Question**

What would be the "clean" way around this? Use the `IDataTable` interface? (I do not want the entire dataset to build up in RAM before it is closed/flushed, I'd rather write on-the-fly.

Or is there no such solution and should I define and implement an `IDataWriter` interface myself.

TIA

Comment: What do you intend to write to? A database? If so, you'll likely need to use a database specific API (or even a generic database API) to do the inserts. If you are writing to a file, you'll like use one of the streaming mechanisms in `System.IO`. `IDataReader` is an abstraction around reading tabular data, the result of applying a _query_ to some datastore. There is no universal abstraction to write data like that

Comment: Indeed I want to write to an arbirary database, of maybe even CSV, Excel or qlik propriatary format. I want to virtualize the (usually table-like) writing process using an interface so it is decoupled from the database implementation classes.